# Why is FTP working over one network and not the another?

Tags: ftp, iis-8

I have a server which is connected to two networks - both of which my machine is also connected to. One is wired, one is wireless. The server is running IIS's built in FTP server.

When I try to connect using filezilla over the wired network (it's IP on this network is 192.168.1.32), I can connect fine and access files no problem.

When I try to connect using filezilla over the wireless network (it's IP on this network is 10.0.0.32), I cannot connect.

It's worth noting that I can connect in both instances using Windows Remote Desktop.

Why is FTP working over one network and not the other?

EDIT: I have disabled the firewall altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your FTP server is binded to both IPs.